# I have migrated to null-safety (2.15.1) and this problem still persists

Tags: flutter, dart, migration

I get the error below when I compile the app.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#73713):
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call(Instance of 'ChangeNotifierProvider<UserLoggedIn>')
```

The error points me to the 'MyApp' part of the code and so I have no idea how to tackle this one.
My app ran with no error before migrating.
This is a part of my code where the cause for this error is.
I went through the code with and I can't find a possible syntax error.

````
    void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulHookWidget {
   @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {


  bool _amplifyConfigured = false;
  bool checkAuthStatus = false;

  late AmplifyAuthCognito auth;


  var userLoggedIn;
  var useProvider;

  @override

  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    if (!mounted) return;


    auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();
    await Amplify.addPlugin(auth);

    try {
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    } on AmplifyAlreadyConfiguredException {
      print('Already configured');
    }

    try {
      getUserStatus();
      setState(() {
        _amplifyConfigured = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userLoggedIn = useProvider(userLoggedInProvider);

    ```
````

Comment: Where are you getting an instance of `ChangeNotifierProvider<UserLoggedIn>`?

Comment: I have no idea how to tackle this one without the `_MyAppState` code . Probably you're appending and extra () at the end of where you read the ChangeNotifierProvider. But its hard to tell without the actual code.

Comment: @croxx5f Hi there, I have edited my question to include more code. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Nitrodon Hi there, I have edited my post to add more code. Does this help in answering your question?

Comment: Did you upgrade Riverpod recently?

Comment: @Nitrodon Yes, I have. Currently using the 1.0.3 version. Perhaps something in the code has been deprecated?

Comment: @Nitrodon It worked. My app runs again. I appreciate your willingness to help me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Riverpod removed `useProvider` in version 1.0.0.  As described in the [migration guide](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.14.0_to_1.0.0/), you will need to use `StatefulHookConsumerWidget` instead of `StatefulHookWidget` to access that same functionality in the newest version:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {
   @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userLoggedIn = ref.watch(userLoggedInProvider);
    // ...
```

Comment: It worked. My app runs again. I appreciate your willingness to help me!